# Embed, Audio, Object Tags are not working in IE 11 and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to play a beep sound on Button Click.
My application is not using HTML5 so we cant use HTML5 DOCType.

Code i have used is-

```
function PlaySound() {
    if (soundObject != null) {
        document.body.removeChild(soundObject);
        soundObject.removed = true;
        soundObject = null;
    }
    soundObject = document.createElement("embed");
    soundObject.setAttribute("src", "Audio/Ping.wav");
    soundObject.setAttribute("hidden", true);
    document.body.appendChild(soundObject);
}
```

The above code working fine Chrome. 
I have tried many solutions but none of them worked.